# How to redirect the user to a new url with sending some data along in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express

[NODE, express] I am making facebook application, where after the user gives the facebook access , facebook redirects the user to my site with a code.
assume it to be

abc.com/heyBuddy/fb/callback?code="adasdasdasda"

In this route i.e router.get('/heyBuddy/fb/callback', funcion(req,res)) , i take the facebook code and do all the necessary computations on the server side, and i can render that data in a html file to the client using res.render.

But i dont want to render on the same url, i.e 'abc.com/heyBuddy/fb/callback' , I want to get the the user code on this url  , do the computations and send that data to another url, i.e abc.com/heybuddy/fbApp and render from there, and so that the user sees the url = abc.com/heybuddy/fbApp.

I tried redirecting, but I was not able to send the computed data along so that i can render that data there.

Can anyone help, how can i got about this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're reimplementing what is already existing with Passport.js and it's Facebook OAuth extension:

- http://passportjs.org/
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

Comment: i dont want to use  passport, is there any way to do this in express itself.   @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('/');   }
```

Comment: what ever data i was showing 'abc.com/heyBuddy/fb/callback' , i want to send that data along also,. any way i can i do that    @Monty